# How to fix Error in BatchGetSymbol download?

Tags: r, cran, rscript

I Have been using batchgetsymbol for months without any issues but today I constantly receive "error in download".
Here's my original R script:

```
us.data7 <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = c("SPY","DIA","QQQ","IWM","SMH","XBI","USO","GLD","UNG","XRT","ARKK","IYT","XLE","XLF"),
first.date = Sys.Date()-28,
last.date = Sys.Date(),
freq.data = 'weekly',
how.to.aggregate = "last",
do.complete.data = FALSE,
thresh.bad.data = 0.75,
cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(),
                                                                                                      'BGS_Cache') ) # cache in tempdir()
Sys.sleep(5)
us.data.out7 <- as_tibble(us.data7$df.tickers)
```

Once I run the script I now receive the following errors:

```
    "SPY | yahoo (1|1) | Not Cached - Error in download..Error in vec_slice():
! x must be a vector, not NULL.
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: ticker.
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: threshold.decision.
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: ticker.
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: price.adjusted. "
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057342/error-in-new-session-could-not-establish-session-after-5-attempts - there seems to be a problem with Yahoo's stock API