# Error in new.session() : Could not establish session after 5 attempts

Tags: r, yahoo-finance, quantmod

I've been facing in R the error message for days using `getSymbols` of the `quantmod` package:

```
Error in new.session() : Could not establish session after 5 attempts.
```

```
getSymbols(tick, from = date_from,  to = date_to, warnings = FALSE, auto.assign = TRUE)
```

The same issue applies to:

```
getSymbols(tick, from = date_from,  to = date_to, warnings = FALSE, auto.assign = TRUE, src="yahoo")
```

Comment: I've also been getting this. It seems to be a server-side problem.

Comment: Same issue when trying to use `quantmod::getQuote()`

Comment: I'm working on getting a fix to CRAN. You can use the development version in the meantime. Follow the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/358)

Comment: `tq_get()` also produced same error msg

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Update QuantMod and try again:

```
install.packages('quantmod')
```

This was a bug that was fixed very swiftly. Thank you Joshua Ulrich!

---

History (2022-04-29):

This was an issue on 2022-04-29 that Joshua Ulrich promptly published a fix for. You could install the patched version with:

```
remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod@358-getsymbols-new.session")
```

But the changes are now into CRAN, so you should just be able to update QuantMod and continue with your day.

Link to fix: [GitHub: joshuaulrich/quantmod@358-getsymbols-new.session](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/tree/358-getsymbols-new.session)

GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/358).

Comment: Not working by Feb 2024. Any update? Thanks!